# launch program in new shell window from python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to launch a python script from another python script in a new shell window. So far I'm unable to do it. Does anyone knows how can I accomplish this?

for example

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('test.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print (process.returncode)
```

when I'll run this script, it should launch 'test.py' in a new a new shell window.

I'm using linux, but it will be very helpful if you can provide solution for windows too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it on Debian-like systems:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
process = subprocess.Popen(
    shlex.split("""x-terminal-emulator -e 'bash -c "test.py"'"""), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print (process.returncode)
```

Something like it should work for any *nix system.

Many thanks to [eudoxos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761090/eudoxos) for pointing out `x-terminal-emulator`!

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` is (at least on Debian and Ubutnu) symlink to the user-selected terminal, and should work always (unlike `gnome-terminal`)

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` is set at the OS level, not on a per-user basis. I don't think it helps to replace `gnome-terminal` with `x-terminal-emulator` since, if `x-terminal-emulator` points to something other than `gnome-terminal` then the arguments `-x bash -c "test.py"` are likely to be invalid or nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized that debian alternatives were system-wide. However, most terminal emulators mimick options of the classical `xterm` program, so using `-e` as the last option (with quoted command) should work just fine for any terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of launching a shell, launch a terminal running your script. On Linux, `xterm -e test.py`; the Windows equivalent would be `cmd.exe test.py` I believe (but I could be wrong).